# Javascript, Redefinition of

Tags: javascript

```
var name; //JSHint :: Redefinition of 'name'.

for(var i=0; i<= 10; i++){
    name = "Hello"+i; //JSHint :: Read only
}
```

JSHint giving warning '**Redefinition of**' for the above code.

I usually writing like that code,

For example)

```
var elementLen = $(".abc").length();
var elementId;
for(var i=0; i<elementLen; i++){
    elementId = $(".class-"+i).data('id');
  //do something using elementId
}
```

In that case, how should I write code correctly?

please advise me,

Edit)

```
var inputLen = $(".input-a").length;
var tmpVal;

for(var i=0; i<inputLen; i++){
    tmpVal = $("#input-a-"+i).val();
  $("#input-a-"+i).val("prefix-"+tmpVal);
}
```

In above case, I can not use tmpVal variable?

Comment: Which line is throwing that warning exactly? Can you show more context?

Comment: For your first sample you don't need a loop: `name = "Hello10";` would work exactly the same. For the second it would be `elementId = $(".class-"+(elementLen - 1)).data('id');` again, without any loops/

Comment: It redefines name = this.name = window.name.

Comment: Your code looks just fine. I would tend to declare `elementId` inside the loop for more clarity, but that really subjective. Maybe did you declare the same variable before that code sample ? If that's not the case, then JSHint must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://jslinterrors.com/redefinition-of-a) page explaining this JSHint error.

There's a `window.name` global which already exists. Try changing the name of you variable from `name` to something else.

Answer (score -3):

It redefines name = this.name = window.name.